# Lots of Directories Bad for Performance?

Tags: performance

I've heard too many images in a single folder can cause performance issues, but does lots of directories create a performance issue? I'm running a website that creates a folder per image uploaded. Down the road I expect to get between 1 million and a few million photos uploaded which means 1-3 million folders. In each folder 6 images are stored with various sizes.

If this is problematic one idea is to have one folder per album which on average could store between 30-90 literal images (the sizes force the number to be multiplied by 6). It's just an idea, what I really want to do is use the best practices for image storage.

So my two options for storage are:

site/images/folder-id/id-size-file-name.jpg (single folder per album)

site/images/folder-id/photo-id/size-file-name.jpg (single folder per image)

Any insights on folder performance will go appreciated.

Comment: Modern filesystems handle hundreds of thousands of entries per directory rather well. Millions, not so sure. Having too many levels might cost you more in performance than having too many files per level. Abstract it out on application level if you can, and experiment a bit. Also, choice of specific filesystem (ext4, btrfs, xfs, zfs, ntfs, ...) may significantly affect performance, too.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of filesystems tend to degrade with the number of entries in a directory, be they files, directories, symbolic links, or other kinds of entries. This is inherent in most methods of storing the entries; the filesystem will have to search through it somehow, though it's possible the search algorithm used has O(log n) time.

The usual way of dealing with this (used by MediaWiki, at least), is to have some sort of uniformly distributed identifier (often a cryptographic hash) and store images in a sort of structure based on prefixes of the hashes. For example, if an image had a hash of `0123456789abcdef`, one might store the image in `01/0123/image.jpg`. You can, of course, tweak it so there are more or less than 256 entries in each level, or add more levels or make other tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for the insights on files within a directory. So does lots of folders within a gallery directory create a performance issue? I'm talking hundreds of thousands and possibly a few million folders in the gallery directory.

I know having the structure too deep can be bad. But what about the quantity of folders possibly creating a performance issue?

Comment: @Josh: I never addressed performance issues from depth; I *only* addressed performance issues due to quantity, and suggested using depth once performance starts to degrade due to quantity. The exact number at which performance starts to degrade depends on lots of factors including your filesystem, operating system, and potentially hardware. You might want to start off simple and then move to a more complicated system once you start noticing a performance issue.